# Solving System of Nonlinear Equations Symbolically

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the following system of three nonlinear equations for the variables $x, y$ and $P$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
0&=r-\theta P-ax -by-cP-q_{1}E_{1}\\
0&=dx-\eta -eP-q_{2}E_{2}\\
0&=\upsilon+\varepsilon xy(1-m)-\gamma_{1}xP-\gamma_{2}yP-nP\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
If there is a software recommendation which solves symbolically or any hint, am happy.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Ok, i have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

From the two first equations solving for $x,y$ we get

$$
\cases{
x = \frac 1d(\eta+e P-q_2E_2) = c_1 P+c_2\\
y = -\frac{1}{b d}(a(\eta e P+q_2E_2)+d((c+\theta)P-r+q_1E_1))= c_3P+c_4
}
$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

No sophisticated software is needed for this case .

Use Eq.(2) get $P=f(x)$ in terms of $x$,
combine that with Eq.(1) to get $y=g(x)$ in terms of $x$,
then substitute $P=f(x),\ y=g(x)$ into Eq.(3)
and solve quadratic equation in $x$.